# can't getting stacked list of widgets after pushing them

Tags: dart, flutter

i created simple app to push and pop random widgets which i listed on variable:

```
List<Widget> _widgets = [TextWidget(), ImageWidget(), ButtonWidget()];
```

in screen i have to button as

- 1) **attach random widget**
- 2) **previous widget**

after click on **attach random widget** i store that in

```
final List<int> _widgetStacks = [0];
```

app work fine with this functions to store them

```
void attachWidget(int index) {
  print(_widgetStacks[index]);
  _widgetStacks.add(index);
  setState(() {
    _currentWidget = index;
  });
}
```

now i want to go back in `_widgetStacks` with clicking on **previous widget** by this functions:

```
getPreviousWidget() {
  if (_widgetStacks.length - 1 > 0) {
    attachWidget(_widgetStacks[_widgetStacks.length - 1]);
  } else {
    _widgetStacks.removeAt(_widgetStacks.length - 1);
    Navigator.pop(context);
  }
}

void getPrevWidget(int index) {
  setState(() {
    _currentWidget = index;
  });
}
```

this functions by multiple click on **previous widget** don't work

my implementation code:

```
void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    title: 'AndroidMonks',
    home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Androidmonks'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.orangeAccent,
      ),
      body: Home(),
    ),
  ));
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  Home({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _Home();
}

class _Home extends State<Home> {
  String title = "Title";
  int _currentWidget = 0;
  final List<int> _widgetStacks = [0];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    attachWidget(_currentWidget);
    List<Widget> _widgets = [TextWidget(), ImageWidget(), ButtonWidget()];

    //TextWidget
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () {
        getPreviousWidget();
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                RaisedButton(
                  child: Text('Attach RANDOM widget'.toUpperCase()),
                  onPressed: () {
                    var rnd = Random();
                    _currentWidget = rnd.nextInt(3);
                    attachWidget(_currentWidget);
                  },
                ),
                RaisedButton(
                  child: Text('PREVIOUS widget'.toUpperCase()),
                  onPressed: () {
                    getPreviousWidget();
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: _widgets[_currentWidget],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void attachWidget(int index) {
    print(_widgetStacks[index]);
    _widgetStacks.add(index);
    setState(() {
      _currentWidget = index;
    });
  }

  void getPrevWidget(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _currentWidget = index;
    });
  }

  getPreviousWidget() {
    if (_widgetStacks.length - 1 > 0) {
      attachWidget(_widgetStacks[_widgetStacks.length - 1]);
    } else {
      _widgetStacks.removeAt(_widgetStacks.length - 1);
      Navigator.pop(context);
    }
  }
}

class ImageWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<ImageWidget> createState() => _ImageWidget();
}

class _ImageWidget extends State<ImageWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Text("ImageWidget"),
    );
  }
}

class TextWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<TextWidget> createState() => _TextWidget();
}

class _TextWidget extends State<TextWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Text("TextWidget"),
    );
  }
}

class ButtonWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<ButtonWidget> createState() => _ButtonWidget();
}

class _ButtonWidget extends State<ButtonWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Text("ButtonWidget"),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check the changes :

In method `attachWidget` every time adding the widget to the `_widgetStacks` and not removing from `_widgetStacks` from `getPreviousWidget`

```
   void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    title: 'AndroidMonks',
    home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Androidmonks'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.orangeAccent,
      ),
      body: Home(),
    ),
  ));
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  Home({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _Home();
}

class _Home extends State<Home> {
  String title = "Title";
  int _currentWidget = 0;
  final List<int> _widgetStacks = [0];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    attachWidget(_currentWidget);
    List<Widget> _widgets = [TextWidget(), ImageWidget(), ButtonWidget()];

    //TextWidget
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () {
        getPreviousWidget();
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                RaisedButton(
                  child: Text('Attach widget'.toUpperCase()),
                  onPressed: () {
                    var rnd = Random();
                    _currentWidget = rnd.nextInt(3);
                    _widgetStacks.add(_currentWidget);
                    attachWidget(_currentWidget);
                  },
                ),
                RaisedButton(
                  child: Text('PREVIOUS widget'.toUpperCase()),
                  onPressed: () {
                    getPreviousWidget();
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: _widgets[_currentWidget],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void attachWidget(int index) {
     setState(() {
      _currentWidget = index;
    });
  }


  getPreviousWidget() {
    if (_widgetStacks.length - 1 > 0) {
      _widgetStacks.removeAt(_widgetStacks.length - 1);
      attachWidget(_widgetStacks[_widgetStacks.length - 1]);
    } else {
      Navigator.pop(context);
    }
  }
}

class ImageWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Text("ImageWidget"),
    );
  }
}

class TextWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Text("TextWidget"),
    );
  }
}

class ButtonWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Text("ButtonWidget"),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: getting list from end to first is not correct, it means i get wrong list when i try to get previous list step by step by click on button